# Fetch then returning _bodyBlob _bodyInit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

When i call my API layer like that in nodejs App.

```
Client.auth(settings.apiBaseUrl, this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log("data: "+ JSON.stringify(data));
                this.props.history.push(data);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                    console.log("error: "+error);
            });
```

auth detail:

```
static auth = (email, adminUrl) => {
    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, admin_url: adminUrl })
    };

    return fetch('https://xxxx/v1/account', config).then(
        Client.returnStatusAndJson
    );
};
returnStatusAndJson = response =>
    response
        .json()
        .then(json => ({ status: response.status, json }))

        .catch(() => ({ status: response.status, json: null }));
```

The router sending this request to middle layer like below

```
this.router.post('/v1/auth', this.sendDashboardSigninUrl.bind(this));
```

I have returning the response with many diffrent type but result always same,
even i have tried **res.json(),res.text(),** **res.end, res.send(data), res.json(data), return data, return data.json(), res.end(data), res.send(JSON.stringify(data)),** every combination...)

Like an example below

```
    sendDashboardSigninUrl(req, res, next) {
        SecurityTokensService.sendDashboardSigninUrl(req)
            .then(data => {
                if(req.body.password == myPwd){
                    console.log("data:"+ JSON.stringify(data));
                    //**i can see right data in here an url with a token**
                    res.send(data); //code return from here with 200 ok
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("error:");
                    throw new Exception("data Error");
                }               
            })
            .catch(next);
    }
}
```

It has using an async function like that:

```
async sendDashboardSigninUrl(req, res) {
        const link = await this.getDashboardSigninUrl(email);
                   //alink coming from here with a code"
            return { link: link };
        } else {
            return { sent: false, error: 'Access Denied' };
        }
    }
}
```

everytime it coming to front-end like that:

```
> data Response {type: "default", status: 200, ok: true, statusText:
> "OK", headers: Headers, …} headers: Headers {map: {…}} ok: true
> status: 200 statusText: "OK" type: "default" url:
> "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/authorize"
> _bodyBlob: Blob {size: 930, type: "application/json"}
> _bodyInit: Blob {size: 930, type: "application/json"}
> __proto__: Object
```

Comment: what does `Client.auth` look like?

Comment: auth just a method name there is no importance with the name molamk. auth just calling router post

Comment: sure but since it's the calling function, providing its code can help solve this

Comment: molamk i have added that snipet too

Answer (score 0):

i got it just coding frontend like that

```
Client.auth(settings.apiBaseUrl, this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
                var pureLink = data;
            })
```